# Powershell : get values ​over 30 rolling days

Tags: powershell, foreach

in a file, I want to make a loop to get for each line the value of the accumulation of the 29 values ​​of the lines which precede this line + the value of the current line but I turn in circles and I do not get the result expected. Can you help me please?

```
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$BLFiles="$DesktopPath\BL.csv" $BL= Import-csv $BLFiles -delimiter ";" -encoding UTF8 | select-object -Last 60
 
$BL30J=0 $day=0
 
foreach ($value in $BL) {
    $day+=1
    if ($day -le 30) {
        $BL30J+=$value."Total" 
        write-host "Day $day : $BL30J" 
    }
}
```

Content of BL.csv:

```
"line";"Total"
"01";"01"
"02";"01"
[...]
"60";"01"
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: I think you're looking for something like `For($i=0;$i -lt 30;$i++){$Last30=$BL[$i..($i+29)] | Measure-Object Total -Sum | % Sum; Write-Host "Day $($i+1) : $Last30"}`

Comment: Why are you grabbing the last 60?

Comment: Because the "Day 30" = value of the sum of the Day 30 to Day 59  value.... "Day 1" = value of the sum of the Day 01 to Day 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "this line" means the most recent, combined with the previous 29, you can simply do this to get the total.

```
Import-Csv $tempfile -Delimiter ';' -Encoding utf8 |
    Select-Object -last 30 -ExpandProperty total |
        Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sum
```

or if you're into shorthand

```
((Import-Csv $tempfile -Delimiter ';' -Encoding utf8 | Select -last 30).total | Measure -Sum).sum
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. the solution proposed by @TheMadTechnician gives me the result I expected. I will be able to continue. thanks again !